# tabindex doesn't work on p:selectOneMenu or h:SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabindex

Tabindex attribute is not working on p:selectOneMenu that I am using in my page. I also have h:inputtext on the same page for which tabindex works fine.

I am using primefaces 4.0. Please help. After the 2nd tabindex it gets lost.

```
<!-- This Dialog page is being used for both ADD & EDIT APPLICANT functionality  -->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


         <h:form id="addApplicantForm">

        <div class="panel" style="width: 540px;">
        <p:outputPanel id="critTabPanel" >
        <div class="dlgHeader">#{applicantForITCController.action} Applicant</div>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5px" style="font-size: 12px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">First Name:</td>
                    <td style="width:65%;padding-right: 5px" align="right">
                        <h:inputText id="firstName-input"  styleClass="suburbinput round5 applyInput" value="#{applicantForITCController.applicantForITCInfo.firstName}" 
                                required="true" requiredMessage="First Name required" onkeypress="return fnb.pl.events.KeyEvents.isStringKey(event)" maxlength="50" tabindex="1"/>
                                <p:watermark for="firstName-input" value="Enter First Name" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%">
                        <p:message for="firstName-input" id="msg-firstName-input" display="icon"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">Last Name:</td>
                    <td style="width:65%;padding-right: 5px" align="right">
                        <h:inputText id="lastName-input"  styleClass="suburbinput round5 applyInput" value="#{applicantForITCController.applicantForITCInfo.lastName}"
                                onkeypress="return fnb.pl.events.KeyEvents.isStringKey(event)" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="Last Name required" tabindex="2"/>
                                <p:watermark for="lastName-input" value="Enter Last Name" />        
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%">
                        <p:message for="lastName-input" id="msg-lastName-input" display="icon"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">Identity Type:</td>
                    <td style="width:65%;">
                    <div class="contGeneric">
                        <div class="colRight">
                            <div class="fnbDropMenu">
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="cri-idType" value="#{applicantForITCController.applicantForITCInfo.idType}"  
                                              required="true" requiredMessage="Please select an Identity Type" styleClass="selectOnDialog" tabindex="3">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select" itemValue=" " noSelectionOption="true"  />                                       
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{applicantForITCController.idTypes}" var="idTy" itemLabel="#{idTy.desc}" itemValue="#{idTy}"/>
                                             <f:validator for="idTypeValidator"
                                                 binding="#{za.co.fnb.propertyleader.interfaces.ui.web.validator.IDTypeValidator}"/>
                                                <f:attribute name="idNum" value="#{idNum}" />
                                 </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%">
                        <p:message for="cri-idType" id="msg-idType" display="icon"  />
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">ID/Passport No:</td>
                    <td style="width:65%;padding-right: 5px" align="right">
                    <h:inputText id="idNumber" binding="#{idNum}" styleClass="suburbinput round5 applyInput" value="#{applicantForITCController.applicantForITCInfo.idNumber}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="ID/Passport Number required" maxlength="30" tabindex="4"/>
                                <p:watermark for="idNumber" value="Enter ID/Passport Number" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%">
                        <p:message for="idNumber" id="msg-idNumber" display="icon" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:30%">Cell Number:</td>
                    <td style="width:65%;padding-right: 5px" align="right">
                    <h:inputText id="cellNo" styleClass="suburbinput round5 applyInput" value="#{applicantForITCController.applicantForITCInfo.cellNo}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Cell Number required" onkeydown="return fnb.pl.events.KeyEvents.isNumericKey(event)" maxlength="10" tabindex="5"/>
                                <p:watermark for="cellNo" value="Enter Cell Number" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:5%">
                        <p:message for="cellNo" id="msg-cellNo" display="icon"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>            
            </table>
            </p:outputPanel>                        

    <div class="btnHolder dblExtraForgotPass" align="center" style="padding-top: 15px;">      

        <a id="colorboxCloseBtn2" class="btn InActive"
           href="javascript:addApplicantDialog.hide();"><span>Cancel</span></a>

         <p:commandLink process="@this @parent" update=":#{p:component('applicantForITCTbl')} :#{p:component('confirmAppPanel')} 
         :#{p:component('critTabPanel')} :#{p:component('msgPnl1')}"
                       action="#{applicantForITCController.updateApplicantForItcList}" styleClass="btn InActive"
                       oncomplete="fnb.pl.property.handleAddApplicantComplete(xhr, status, args)">
            <span>Save</span>
        </p:commandLink>

    </div> 
   </div>       
   </h:form>


</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Do you have `<h:head/>` on your page and have you observed this behaviour across multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes. On all Browsers tabindex getting lost.I have put the complete page code